# Is it possible to safe cast a string to a datetime in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a string column that usually has date data so I do some replaces to get it into proper format and I safe cast to datetime, but all the rows are null when I know the data comes out in proper format, any alternative ideas?

```
SELECT 
-- what I use to proper format for conversion e.g. '22-04-2022 07:39:00'
REPLACE(REPLACE(TESTDATE, "," , ""), ".", "-") AS x ,

-- place it into safe cast expecting proper dates to cast and others to null
SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(TESTDATE, "," , ""), ".", "-") AS DATETIME FORMAT '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') AS y,
TESTDATE
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

from this i get :

```
 x                   y       TESTDATE
22-04-2022 07:39:00  null   22.04.2022, 07:39:00
```

Comment: my issue is the column labeled z returns null always, I'm expecting it to convert the valid dates and return nulls for the invalid ones

Comment: `'1998-10-18 13:45:55'` seems to be a correct datetime so, problem is unclear.... you need to do some explanation 

Comment: i have updated my problem, but yes my thoughts exactly, the dates are coming out fine in string form but just don't cast

Comment: The definition (=DDL) of the table `TEST_TABLE` would be of help, to people with more knowledge of google-bigquery tan I have ....

Comment: TEST_TABLE is just raw table and TESTDATE is a string column in it, generally the strings in TESTDATE look as in the result set but sometimes they're 'nan' which is why im trying to safe cast here

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
SELECT 
-- what I use to proper format for conversion e.g. '22-04-2022 07:39:00'
TRANSLATE(TESTDATE, ".," , "-") AS x ,

-- place it into safe cast expecting proper dates to cast and others to null
SAFE.PARSE_DATETIME('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', TRANSLATE(TESTDATE, ".," , "-")) AS y,
TESTDATE
FROM TEST_TABLE
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `'%d.%m.%Y, %T'` format string looks enough for your purpose if you want to get `DATETIME` value.

```sql
DECLARE TESTDATE DEFAULT '22.04.2022, 07:39:00';

SELECT TESTDATE, SAFE.PARSE_DATETIME('%d.%m.%Y, %T', TESTDATE);
```